# local storage not accepting value from object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, storage, local

im trying to set x's age to the local storage item 'age' however, for a reason i do not know, this will not work.

Here is my code:

```
var x = {
age: 37,
gender: "male",
income: 17000,
};
localStorage.setItem("age") = x.age;
alert(localStorage.getItem('age'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your **[syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**. You need to use it this way.

```
localStorage.setItem("age", x.age)

alert(localStorage.getItem('age'));
```

The idea is simple. You are storing the data against a name. And then retrieve it using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Then look at [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) which says:

> ```
> storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);
> ```

Then get your syntax correct:

```
var x = {
  age: 37,
  gender: "male",
  income: 17000,
};
localStorage.setItem("age", x.age);
alert(localStorage.getItem('age'));
```